# sofascore team lineup missing player python

Tags: python

there is an url https://api.sofascore.com/api/v1/event/11352533/lineups that give the linups and missing data how i can take the missing player from the url i mean how i can find the id for each team for each league ?

i want to got missing player in python
i mean take real id and build the http

Request URL:
https://api.sofascore.com/api/v1/event/11352533/lineups
Request Method:
GET
Status Code:
200 OK
Remote Address:
104.22.76.142:443
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.